# Polymorphic Anonymous Functions Type Aliases

Tags: javascript, flowtype

It seems there's a subtle difference between type decleration for named `function()` syntax vs anonynous function syntax:

```
type F<X, Y> = (x: X) => Y

// works:
function apply<X, Y>(f: F<X, Y>, x: X) : Y {
    return f(x)
}

// works:
const apply0 : <X, Y>(f: F, x: X) => Y = (f, x) => f(x)

// doesn't work
const apply1 : <X, Y>(f: F<X, Y>, x: X) => Y = (f, x) => f(x)
```

[Flow console snippet](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYgPADQDRQJoD4oF4oAoAeAXFAgJTaaoBQAZgK4B2AxsAJYD2DUAhmGADYhEKDLhrF4yNOhRES5YqigBvKlHVQAThGB1NXGgVJUAvlSacAzsB59BABijFh0sRNnEyFNNjw1Z5FiYhvjGFgzWtgIgAIxOUC6i4rCJMlByXkE+OGIB3iHGVLzRMQTe+FAAVFAATCgA5Nz1xsWCpRVZFdV1UDHG6kA)

I need to remove generic type annotation from any reference to type `F<X, Y>` in the arguments of anonymous `apply` function for type checker to work.

This is counterintuitive.

[Edit:] But it seems that Flow is able to type check `apply1` calls even though it fails to type check `apply1` itself:

```
apply1(x => x * 2, 'a') // error: ^ string. This type is incompatible with
apply1(x => x * 2, 1) // works
```

More generally:

```
// works:
type Apply<X, Y> = <X, Y>(f: F, x: X) => Y

const apply : Apply = (f, x) => f(x)    


// doesn't work:
type Apply1<X, Y> = <X, Y>(f: F<X, Y>, x: X) => Y

const apply1 : Apply1 = (f, x) => f(x)
```

[Flow console snippet](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYgPADQDRQJoD4oF4oAoAeAXFAgJTaaoBQokUAgmGADYiIobZTtrq4BmxGCiIlyWSjXDRGLEAEYenHEr6DYqkcTIU0VKgGMA9gDsAzsCgBDJqyjFZdnAJHjM-AqUOmL12wvsGf3kuFyh8NygPCP0bOQJdfCgAKigAJhQAcitM8gB6PKgIfEgDYAgAEyKAJ2qjapQAIwBXS1poAwALCAMAazMqONYEiXCU9JR5LyGFEcwk1IyobNyoApq66uszIpKe8orB4LmxxcmvKCggA)

I have to remove generic type annotation `X, Y` from the arguments of type alias `Apply` for Flow to type check it.

Is it the intended behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't use Flow and am not the most familiar with generic types, but it sure seems like all the `X` and `Y` should align respectively. Furthermore, given your `Apply` type that does work, it seems like this definition should fail: `var res: String = apply((val) => 123, "abc")`, but it passes.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The only definition that correctly type checks `apply(x => x * 2, 'a')` is the named function version.

Comment: I think the parameter `f: F` must be seen as `f: F<Any, Any>` where `Any` is whatever Flow uses to represent *any* possible type. Even this compiles: `var res: String = apply((val: Boolean) => 123, "abc")`. Probably need to file a report.

Comment: I am not sure which type system Flow is based on but my guess is that this problem has something to do with variance.

Comment: Even if we define explicit types `Apply<String, Number>` and then pass something other than a string to the second param of `apply()`, [it compiles](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYgPADQDRQJoD4oF4oAoAeAXFAgJTaaoBQokUAgmGADYiIobZTtrq4BmxGCiIlyWSlSoBjAPYA7AM7AoAQyasoxRizYBlYACcAlvIDmKAHIBXALYAjCIcw44Bk+at3HzgSPGY-ASkUgBuqoZQhhCKxO6mZlzquri44cwBUOkAdMCyADKyAO5OAMKqihC4pCjW8gAmEPymEPUhUB1QQA). ...but then I'm tinkering with a type system that I haven't actually learned, so who knows. Do me a favor and drop a note here if you get some resolution. I'm curious to see how this pans out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR: Try

```
const apply1 = <X, Y>(f: F<X, Y>, x: X): Y => f(x)
```

### Explanation

First, as @squint mentioned in a comment, `F` without type arguments implicitly means `F<any, any>`, which is why `apply0` works in your example.

So why does your `apply1` have an error? Well, it's due to the fact that Flow does not infer generics. so when you wrote

```
const apply1 : <X, Y>(f: F<X, Y>, x: X) => Y = (f, x) => f(x)
```

the right hand side of the assignment is

```
(f, x) => f(x)
```

and Flow can't infer that this arrow function is polymorphic. So you could just add type parameters to the RHS like this:

```
const apply1 : <X, Y>(f: F<X, Y>, x: X) => Y = <X, Y>(f: F<X, Y>, x: X): Y => f(x)
```

and that should fix the error. But at this point, the type annotation on the left hand side is no longer necessary. So you can simplify it to

```
const apply1 = <X, Y>(f: F<X, Y>, x: X): Y => f(x)
```

### Further reading

Avik Chaudhuri wrote a short explanation on a [similar stack overflow question](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2165#issuecomment-236868389), which in turn links to a [similar answer on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2165#issuecomment-236868389)