# Flowtype Javascript Inference Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, flowtype

I'm unable to figure out why Flow cannot correctly infer the return type from the Reference #1 map function if Reference #2 is not commented out.

If Reference #2 is commented out OR if I explicitly denote `Mappable<B>` as the return type for Reference #1 all is good.

```
const map = <A, B>(transform: Transform<A, B>, mappable: Mappable<A>): Mappable<B> => mappable.map(transform);
```

Would love to know why this is working the way it is! Thanks!

```
// Types
type Transform<A, B> = (value: A) => B;

// Classes
class Mappable<A> {
  __value: A;
  constructor(value: A) {
    this.__value = value;
  }
  map<B>(transform: Transform<A, B>): Mappable<B> {
    return new Mappable(transform(this.__value));
  }
}

class Container<A> extends Mappable<A> {}

// Transformations
const stringToBase10Number = (value: string): number => parseInt(value, 10);
const numberToString = (value: number): string => value.toString();

// Map Utility (Reference #1)
const map = <A, B>(transform: Transform<A, B>, mappable: Mappable<A>) => mappable.map(transform);

// Log Utility
const log = <T>(value: T): T => { console.log(value); return value; }

// Test Case
const fooContainer = new Container('10');

const fooNumberContainer = map(stringToBase10Number, fooContainer);
map(log, fooNumberContainer); // Logs '1' to the console

// Reference #2
const fooStringContainer = map(numberToString, fooNumberContainer);
map(log, fooStringContainer);
```

Error:

```
const fooStringContainer = map(numberToString, fooNumberContainer);
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function call
const map = <A, B>(transform: Transform<A, B>, mappable: Mappable<A>) => mappable.map(transform);
                ^ B. This type is incompatible with
const numberToString = (value: number): string => value.toString();
                               ^^^^^^ number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a return type to the `map` function. So change

```
const map = <A, B>(transform: Transform<A, B>, mappable: Mappable<A>) => mappable.map(transform);
```

to

```
const map = <A, B>(transform: Transform<A, B>, mappable: Mappable<A>): Mappable<B> => mappable.map(transform);
```

[Your full example before](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgCoE8AOApgM6oAuBhOATgIYB2xUc1AtgDwCCANGAEIA+MAF4wACgButGAFdCALjCcAlCKF8A3OkxgAwjFrFiJVAGMDRsAFla+fLQBGMQlyEBvVGDAB9b1NkKSlpepnCMZNQypmQsktJyiipgHl5eZAAWAJbEAHS+-nIiYAWEwWAAvp5grLbsgmIRDEwsrIrYdIzMbFy8gsqKNnaOznXuVV7UhGQy1PRg9IRIg-ZOhA0dzWwNWbn58YTKymWVlWYWxHphZLSZC9SuYIQAHmSE9AAmF8vDLpzupzp2k0ujUyJkwqRQuEwMQIrcAObYOB8QyEACMAAYAHIyVgOQjUIpxAKKWHUBH9ea4-GE4RCezUYwASXoZGJcl4mKOZghZCpeIJSIAynD6PCiSVFPRqQTKWSEWpivscjEReSxWJuRgsIMwABVMEwTIUcQAJUIUAJb1MVAAxGjlDzoTV8EUevwBOtgS02hsQe7BLwXStnANbCHfgJVHTquGfjkXV7Oi0tToADJwcUGzJGihO2FgeDi0TsbCeyU4SnYRVuMBQ4hwZw5Ivsg4aMCTaazJUBdsArDYEh83So-N85hwXRXG53IoLJBT1kzgliADkmNXWvr47gcBxAuoi+utwJRUT8rFSJRxkx+5pvAnR+X1G5iaLD93d4JT5PL-b6czC511XMAYlA9IqHrRtCG0LBzUtSZ6BtMBbQAJjHMAJzVBEf1nURE2lA9hVFeEPz3GVD2nX9X1sMR30w3dsLFXDZQ0IA)

[Your full example after](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgCoE8AOApgM6oAuBhOATgIYB2xUc1AtgDwCCANGAEIA+MAF4wACgButGAFdCALjCcAlCKF8A3OkxgAwjFrFiJVAGMDRsAFla+fLQBGMQlyEBvVGDAB9b1NkKSlpepnCMZNQypmQsktJyiipgHl5eZAAWAJbEAHS+-nIiYAWEwWAAvp5grLbsgmIRDEwsrIrYdIzMbFy8gsqKNnaOznXuVV7UhGQy1PRg9IRIg-ZOhA0dzWwNWbn58YTKymWVlWYWxHphZLSZC9SuYIQAHmSE9AAmF8vDLpzupzp2k0ujUyJkwqRQuEwMQIrcAObYOB8QyEACMAAYAHIyVgOQjUIpxAKKWHUBH9ea4-GE4RCezUYwASXoZGJcl4mKOZghZCpeIJSIAynD6PCiSVFPRqQTKWSEWpivscjEReSxWJuRgsIMwABVMEwTIUcQAJUIUAJb1MVAAxGjlDzoTV8EUevwBOtgS02hsQe7BLwXStnANbCHfgJKd9VqNFcGfjkXV7Oi0tToADJwcUGzJGihO2FgeDi0TsbCeyU4SnYRVuMBQ4hwZw5Evsg4aMCTaazJUBTsArDYEh83Sowt85hwXRXG53IoLJAz1lzgliADkmPXWsbk7gcBxAuoy+utwJRWT8rFSJRxkxh5pvCnJ9X1G5yZLT-3D4JL7Pb87TNswuTd1zAGJwPSKhG2bQhtCwc1LUmegbTAW0ACYJzAKc1QRP951EZNpSPYVRXhL8DxlY9Z3-d9bDET9sP3XCxXw2UNCAA)

Why is this return type annotation needed? It's because Flow does not infer polymorphic types. If the function always returned a `string`, it wouldn't matter. But since it returns `Mappable<B>`, the annotation is needed.

Here is another answer that also addresses this problem: [Polymorphic Anonymous Functions Type Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814690/polymorphic-anonymous-functions-type-aliases/38833703#38833703)

Comment: Ah! "Flow does not infer polymorphic types" <— Haven't seen this documented anywhere, so I wasn't sure if it was a bug. Thank you!